# Android Studio high cpu usage when NOT building

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

For me Android studio is using all of my cpu and the fans on my laptop is maxing out all the time. This is when NOT building or doing anything but just coding.
I can understand that it revs up during build but i cant understand what is using >100% cpu when just coding. Do anybody know a way of fixing this? Pleas do not suggest turning on power saving mode, Android studio is useless when powersaving is on.. I want code completion and such things to be turned on.  I should mention that i use experimental gradle and android ndk and writing code in c/c++

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar issue. Android Studio 2.1 Prev 3 invokes and closes git.exe (very often) and uses CPU up to 100% (Win 8.1 x64, Git 2.7.4).

I've disabled the "git integration" plugin and AS works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. disabled all plugins but still same. also i do not have git installed.